# MYSQL to MS SQL Query Conversion

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

I have MySQL query. I want to execute this query in MS SQL Server.
How can I convert MySQL to MS SQL.

```
SELECT  DST.name AS name,
        BWT.name AS name,
        FOD.name AS name,   
        GROUP_CONCAT(ODH.name SEPARATOR ';') as name, 
FROM DST 
LEFT join BWT 
    on DST.name = BWT.name 
LEFT join firstorderdata as FOD 
    on DST.name = FOD.name 
LEFT join ODH 
    on DST.name = ODH.name 
WHERE DST.dist_status != 'T' 
group by DST.name
```

And also I want to generate `csv` for this query result if possible.

if anybody know please help me ...

Comment: I guess you know that there is no group_concat in sql server but if you google sqlserver group_concat you should find something useful. It would help elicit answers if you added sample data as text to your question or sqlfiddle together with expected results as text or sqlfiddle.

Comment: BTW bwt.name,and fod.name will be indeterminate and you cannot have multiple aliases with the same name.

Comment: @P.Salmon Of course there is `GROUP_CONCAT` equivalent :)

Comment: @lad2025 Thanks for the update.

Comment: Please tell us for which tables the `name` column is unique. It looks like there can only be one record per `name` in DST, in BWT and in FOT, but there can be mutliple records for a `name` in ODH. Is this so? (If so, can you explain why DST, BWT, and FOT are separate tables?)

Comment: Sorry actually i showed example one. the column name is not same for all table. the column name is unique.

Answer (score 1):

From `SQL Server 2017` you could use [STRING_AGG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-agg-transact-sql):

```
SELECT  DST.name AS name,
        BWT.name AS name,
        FOD.name AS name,   
        STRING_AGG(ODH.name, ';') as name    --changed
FROM DST 
LEFT join BWT 
    on DST.name = BWT.name 
LEFT join firstorderdata as FOD 
    on DST.name = FOD.name 
LEFT join ODH 
    on DST.name = ODH.name 
WHERE DST.dist_status != 'T' 
group by DST.name AS name,
        BWT.name AS name,    -- added
        FOD.name AS name;    -- added
```

---

Columns should have distinctive aliases:

```
SELECT  DST.name AS d_name,
        BWT.name AS b_name,
        FOD.name AS f_name,
```